# Unassigned variable value

Tags: c++, variables

When I use the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    while(1) {
        int a;
        if(a != 0) {
            cout << a << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program never stops.

I learned that unassigned variables store whatever there is in the specific location in memory.
 ***Why always the value of a is 0?***

Maybe because its my large memory capacity or its just the compiler?
I use GNU compiler C++ 11
I use Release build configuration.
I'm also newbie to this language.

***EDIT:***
I use g++ compiler, got my answer.

Comment: Unassigned variables exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: UB is UB.  You cannot expect `a` to be anything.

Comment: How can you say *always*?

Comment: It's just random. It could even be reproducible on your machine, but it doesn't mean it is always like that. Changing optimization flags, or compiler, or architecture, or whatever, could give you different results.

Comment: In that simple example it is likely to be 0 as (at least for Windows) you get new mem pages from the zero page pool so that you can't 'spy' on other processes freed pages and possibly get secure data - but as other's have said don't rely on that. As soon as you alloc / free memory and reuse previous memory from your own process (which the stdlib could also do) you will see 'garbage' in uninitialized data

Comment: Uninitialized values result in undefined (unpredictable) behaviour; thus you are "not allowed" to use this value. For example reading the same uninitialized variable can return different values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the compiler and options. Formally you have an *indeterminate value*. But the g++ compiler tends to set those variables to 0.

Thinking about what happens at the machine code level, if `a` is 0 the first time execution passes through the declaration, there is nothing in the program that reasonably could cause the value in that memory location to change, so then you get an infinite loop.

At the source code level, however, use of that indeterminate value (including just checking it) incurs formal Undefined Behavior, where anything or nothing can happen, including that what one expects would happen, happens. :)

Comment: I just realized I fooled myself. I actually use g++ compiler. Oh my....

Comment: The GNU C++ compiler is g++. It usually, in my experience, sets local variables to zero if they're not initialized. But I haven't read any guarantee of that, and other compilers generally don't.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to ask which compiler does not set UB values? I know they generally much faster than g++

Comment: @Shlomi: I think most compilers won't clear local variables by default. For example, Visual C++ doesn't. There is no such thing as "UB values" though :) But I think I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Reading an uninitialized variable is "undefined behaviour" - meaning "anything can happen, your compiler is free to do whatever it pleases" (and not just to the variable in question, actually to your *entire* program).

Don't invoke undefined behaviour in your programs. Or suffer the (unpredictable) consequences.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not assign a value to a variable, and then reference it, the behavior of the program is not defined as that value could be whatever garbage was by luck at that memory location. In your case, luck has it that it is always zero. If you change the operating system/compiler/compiler options or even just what is going on in the operating system you could very well have different results.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I did not read this answer before, but it explains a lot to me now. I asked my father the same question and you gave it like him. I understand that UB is very dangerous and MUST be avoided.